# How can I pass Data in URL

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, post, query-string

How can I pass data through my URL ?

I need to pass, an email, client_id, etc.

```
Client.aspx?Email='teste@gmail.com'
```

Nowadays I have an Javascript Function, but I think would be better via Code-Behind

```
    $('.btIncluirAtendimento').live('click', function () {
        idCliente = $(this).attr('id').replace('cad_', '');
        popup = openPopup('../Cliente/AtendimentoNew.aspx?Cliente_Id=' + idCliente, 'IncluirAtendimento', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=no', '720', '600', 'true');
    });


function openPopup(theURL, winName, features, myWidth, myHeight, isCenter) {
    if (window.screen) if (isCenter) if (isCenter == "true") {
        var myLeft = (screen.width - myWidth) / 2;
        var myTop = (screen.height - myHeight) / 2;
        features += (features != '') ? ',' : '';
        features += ',left=' + myLeft + ',top=' + myTop;
    }
    popup = window.open(theURL, winName, features + ((features != '') ? ',' : '') + 'width=' + myWidth + ',height=' + myHeight);
    return popup;
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the url string and than you can pass data easily.

Example :

```
   Server.URLEncode("http://www.w3schools.com?mykey=datavalue");
```

Comment: You should not encode the whole string, but only the value of the parameters, i.e. `"http://www.w3schools.com?mykey=" + Server.URLEncode("datavalue");`

Comment: @Jan Aagaard - this just ans example....well main point to show the method ...and use of the method is depends on your need

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. First, URL-encode the values, like this. (Encoding a number will not do anything, so the second UrlEncode could be left out if all client IDs are numbers.)

```
string url = String.Format("Client.aspx?Email={0}&ClientId={1}",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("test@gmail.com"),
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1234"));
```

This will give you this url:

```
"Client.aspx?Email=test%40gmail.com&ClientId=1234"
```

You can read the values in Client.aspx.cs with these line of code:

```
string emailAddress = Request.QueryString["Email"];
int clientId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["ClientId"]);
```

Remember to check parameters. Int32.Parse() will throw an exception if ClientId is not a number.

Comment: If I would pass 2 data ? like, Email and ClienteID ?  How can I separate ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to encode the critical characters. Look [here](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) for a desacription the characters. Your URL has to look like this:

```
Client.aspx?Email=teste%40gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx